# How can I get lat/lang with Geocode?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

I have an address, and now I need to retrieve the Lat / Lang coordinates.
At Google, [they only have good examples](http://code.google.com/intl/no/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding) for V2 and not V3.

I want to do the following:

```
var myLatLAng = getLatLang(adress);
```

How can I modify this code to make that happend?

```
function showAddress(address) {
  geocoder.getLatLng(
    address,
    function(point) {
      if (!point) {
        alert(address + " not found");
      } else {
        map.setCenter(point, 13);
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        map.addOverlay(marker);
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(address);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return any value because `getLatLng` is using callback function so it can only interact with your enviroment.
You can assign it to some other variable

```
var lat, lng;
function showAddress(address) {
    ...
    } else {
         lat = point.lat();
         lng = point.lng();

         orExecuteOtherfunction();
    }
}
```

Or execute some other function that will do something with your returned point.

Comment: Yeah... that's what I feared :(. Thanks.